# Declaring a global CSS variable generates error in Dreamweaver

Tags: css, global-variables, dreamweaver

As found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) I am trying to declare a golbal CSS variable in a root element. The html displays correctly and I cannot find any error except the one Dreamweaver tells me:

- "Expected RBRACE at line 5, col 3"
- "Expected RBRACE at line 6, col 3"
- ...

It seems as I could ignore DW here, but it leaves a bad feeling in my gut. Am I missing something obvious, or is DW wrong?

[image: Error]

Comment: Nothing to worry about. Simply Dreamweaver is older than the CSS variables. I use Dreamweaver CS6 and it generates errors for all new CSS features.

Comment: I see. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.